# Why does gas exist, why not have opcodes cost specific amounts of wei?

Tags: gas

Why would a system like: Each opcode cost a specific amount of wei, and then the total transaction you pay is the sum of opcodes*opcode fee in wei + Priority fee in wei ? So that there's no gas and all the fighting for blockspace happens in the priority fee?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason that gas is chosen over some amount of wei is supply and demand. If transactions cost a certain amount of wei, then they always cost the same amount. This way, network always charges the same amount while demand can change drastically throughout the lifetime of the network.

By using gas, when there is low demand, fees are going to be lower. When there is a high demand, the costs go higher. This can also be thought as a defence mechanism against network clogging. Where an attacker needs to pay more and more if he wants to launch a denial of service against the whole network.

More information can be found [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/) and [EIP-1559](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559).